# How to solve this error "create_text_channel Error"

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I don't know what this happen.
I created a text_channel, but it give me this error.
And I didn't find what is false.
Please help me to solve this problem.

```
Ignoring exception in command tk:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 83, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/FunMc/cmds/ticket.py", line 22, in tk
    ticket = await guild.create_text_channel(f"questions-{r.randint(0,99999)}", overwrites=overwrites)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/guild.py", line 869, in create_text_channel
    channel = TextChannel(state=self._state, guild=self, data=data)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/channel.py", line 107, in __init__
    self._update(guild, data)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/channel.py", line 131, in _update
    self._fill_overwrites(data)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/abc.py", line 294, in _fill_overwrites
    self._overwrites.append(_Overwrites(id=overridden_id, **overridden))
TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'allow_new'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 892, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 797, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 92, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'allow_new'
```

```py
member = ctx.author
guild = ctx.guild
overwrites = {
        guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
        guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, manage_channels=True, send_messages=True, manage_messages=True, manage_roles=True),
        member: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
}
ticket = await guild.create_text_channel(f"questions-{r.randint(0,99999)}", overwrites=overwrites)
```

Comment: This is a known bug with how dpy handles the creation of channels and has been noted on the github, can you show your code? Also can we get the output of `python -m discord -v` please

Comment: ok, it is on here.

Comment: I dont see any issues with that code, so its definitely the bug coming into play here. What version of dpy are you using?

Comment: I use 1.3.4 versions

Comment: I have same issue on 1.3.3. Bot has been running for many months and out of the blue this error starts happening. EDIT: Updating to 1.3.4 fixed this for me it seems.

Comment: Yea its due to discord changing there api without sharing by the sounds of it, you can read more about it here. https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/5109

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happened same for me:

[image]

I've got no idea what happened, I even reverted to latest working and tested out version of my code, where it actually created a room. But now a few days later it just doesn't. And spits out :

[image]

As you may see it never got through the `"create_text_channel"`

Comment: Yea, its known and an issue on the api itself. You can read more about it here https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/5109

Comment: ok. So, I need to wait the author to change this bug.

Answer (score 1):

Simply update discord.py

## Linux/macOS

python3 -m pip install -U discord.py

## Windows

py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py

Comment: I use repl.it, not computer.

Comment: The website tells me they have discord.py 1.3.4 available - try updating it in the package manager

Comment: I just use 1.3.4 not other version.